# How to put two different textboxes into same level?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Right xaml code looks this way:

```
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="363" Height="628">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,-105,-9,0">
            <StackPanel MinWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="474" Height="459">


            </InlineUIContainer>
            <Run Language="ru-ru"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Language="ru-ru" Text="Num1"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <TextBox d:DesignUseLayoutRounding="True" 
                         Width="160" 
                         UseLayoutRounding="True" 
                         Text="Enter num" 
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                         x:Name="TxtBlock_numRequest"
                         InputMethod.IsInputMethodEnabled="False" 
                         Height="23" 
                         AutoWordSelection="True"/>
            </InlineUIContainer>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Language="ru-ru"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Language="ru-ru" Text="ID"/>
            <Run Text="    "/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <TextBox Width="160" 
                         Text="Enter num" 
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                         x:Name="TxtBlock_IDWork" 
                         Height="23"/>
```

As you can there are two textboxes, which located one under other one, and I need to put them into same level, I tried it to via constructor, it simply don't do it in my particular case. To clearify I have added pictures.

[image: Q]

And don't be afraid foreign inscriptiones, its doesn't matter.
[image]

I just don't know how to fix this, and I think it' related with `StackPanel`. Any ideas ?

UPD: All xaml code here http://snipt.org/Btff4/Default#expand
UPD: May be it possible to put one more stack panel rigt to existing one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably looking for Orientation attribute:

```
<StackPanel MinWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="474" Height="459" Orientation="Horizontal">
```

**Update**

Adding a very basic example to illustrate how StackPanel works:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestBench.Stackpanel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
        <TextBox Text="First textbox" Height="20" Margin="5, 0" />
        <TextBox Text="Second textbox" Height="20" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Execution result:

[image: Textboxes]

**Update**

Adding XAML which allows to achieve desired layout:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestBench.Stackpanel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Sample layout" SizeToContent="Height" Width="400">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" Content="Задайте параметры заявок" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" />

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="номер заявки" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="Введите число" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="приоритет заявки" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" SelectedIndex="0">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Высокий" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Средний" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Низкий" />
            </ComboBox>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="идентификатор вида работы" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="Введите число" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="номер траектории" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Text="Введите число" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Execution result:

[image: Desired layout]

Comment: May be it should work, but then I added such property, my all objects disappeared. After I returned to vertical, and eventually returned to previous condition/

Comment: May be easiest way just to don't use this `StackPanel`?

Comment: Could you please post a clearer version of your XAML? Currently it's in such a mess, I can't event understand how everything works at all.

Comment: I added code, but it mostly generated by VS, this is why it really hard to understand

Comment: In the meantime you can download and use a visual/logical tree browser, like WPF Inspector http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com. The fact that you can't see some objects doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: Ok, I finally downloaded your code and it has *absolutely* nothing in common with the one posted in your original question. Please note, that it isn't WinForms, so using designer only is not an option. Positioning all your elements using margins will lead you nowhere.

Comment: I really sorry for wrong link, I provided true one now. I will try to use your code.

Comment: I reviewed the last portion of code you posted. You have all your elements inside a TextBlock, making it almost impossible to change layout. I strongly doubt that such approach should be followed. Please see my updated answer for a *very* simplified example of how your goal can be achieved (note, that this is only one of possible solutions).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `StackPanel` with `Orientation="Horizontal"`, as a container. Something like:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Label</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Width="150"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Label 2</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Width="150"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Grid defintion than StakPanel. You can easily design your application with that method, just cut each area in many smaller area. Use `Auto` and `*` to define proportion.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Label" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <Label Content="Label" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Text="Text here !" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBox Text="Text here !" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Label Content="I need this kind of location" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Grid should do what you need:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock   Name="lblTextBlock1" Text="Text Block" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox Text="TextBlock1" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="5,0,0,0" MaxHeight="20"  MinWidth="100" MaxLength="4" MaxWidth="40"></TextBox>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"   Name="lblTextBlock2" Text="Text Block" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"  Text="TextBlock2" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="5,0,0,0" MaxHeight="20"  MinWidth="100" MaxLength="4" MaxWidth="40"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```